Дважды обновляется экран приложения на Compose. Что не так?
Есть классическое приложение с двумя экранами - на первом список, на втором подробности. Для списка используется пагинация Paging 3. (для меня это новое)
Проблема в том, что при переходе на второй экран и возвращении назад экран со списком обновляется дважды. Очевидно, проблема где-то в том что дважды вызывается обновление данных, но я в упор не вижу где. Если сделать загрузку просто 100 элементов из списка, то никаких проблем.
Помогите, пожалуйста, увидеть ошибку.
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    component.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = POKEMONS_LIST_SCREEN
        ) {
            composable(POKEMONS_LIST_SCREEN) {
                val data = pokemonsListViewModel.getPokemonList().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
                PokemonListScreen(
                    data = data,
                    pokemonsListViewModel = pokemonsListViewModel) {
                    navController.navigate("$POKEMONS_DETAILS_SCREEN/$it")
                }
            }
            composable("$POKEMONS_DETAILS_SCREEN/{name}") { name ->
                val pokemonName = name.arguments?.getString("name")
                PokemonDetailsScreen(
                    pokemonDetailsViewModel = pokemonDetailsViewModel,
                    name = pokemonName
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PokemonListScreen(
    data: LazyPagingItems<PokemonListResult>,
    pokemonsListViewModel: PokemonsListViewModel,
    onClickNav: (String) -> Unit
) {

    Log.d("Qaz", "qaz")
    Scaffold(){innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)){
            when (data.loadState.refresh) {
                is LoadState.Error -> {}
                LoadState.Loading -> {}
                is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                    LazyColumn {
                        items(data) { item ->
                            Card(Modifier.clickable {
                                if (item != null) {
                                    onClickNav(item.name)
                                }
                            }) {
                                if (item != null) {
                                    Text(text = "${item.name}")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class PokemonsListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val pokemonList: GetPokemonList
) : ViewModel() {

    fun getPokemonList() = pokemonList.getPokemonList()
}


class PokemonPagingSource(
    private val loader: PokemonApi
) : PagingSource<Int, PokemonListResult>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, PokemonListResult>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, PokemonListResult> {
        val key = params.key ?: 0
        val offset = params.loadSize * key
        return try {
            val response = loader.getPokemonList(limit = params.loadSize, offset = offset)
            val pokelist = response.pokelist
            val nextKey = if (pokelist.size < params.loadSize) null else key + 1
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = pokelist,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = nextKey
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}

class PokemonRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api: PokemonApi
) : PokemonRepository {

    override fun getPokemonList(): Flow<PagingData<PokemonListResult>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE, initialLoadSize = PAGE_SIZE),
            pagingSourceFactory = { PokemonPagingSource(loader = api) }
        ).flow
    }
    
    override suspend fun getPokemonDetails(name: String): PokemonDetails {
        return api.getPokemonDetailsByName(name)
    }

    companion object {
        const val PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
 }


Что значит дважды? Типичная проблема - при возвращении назад список  загружается заново, что нужно лечить с помощью .cachedIn(viewModelScope). Также бывает проблема с получением Flow потому что composable отрабатывает дважды (неожиданно, но факт. вроде из-за hilt). Но это не ваш случай хоть в коде вы не предоставили как вы предоставляете Flow<PagingData

Спасибо за  .cachedIn(viewModelScope) . Но это не решает проблемы. Дважды - это значит при возвращении происходит загрузка списка и через мгновение экран моргает и снова загружает список.

Ну видимо собака порылась в двойном вызове getPokemonList() (двойной вызов composable из-за hilt. Я писал issue, но его закрыли как "не требует фикса"). У меня это свойство которое я присваиваю в init и поэтому Flow всегда тот же объект. Мой косяк. SO подсветка залила серым fun getPokemonList() = pokemonList.getPokemonList() и я подумал что это закомментировано. Еще и придрался что вы реализацию getPokemonList() не притащили )

А всё просто оказалось - ответ кроется здесь:
class PokemonsListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val pokemonList: GetPokemonList
) : ViewModel() {

    fun getPokemonList() = pokemonList.getPokemonList()
}

Если сделать вот так:
val state = pokemonList.getPokemonList().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

то всё работает.
